# CTRPP failed, error code is -2147024894

Tags: windows, performancecounter

I am adding performance counter's manifest file to an existing project, and I configure the compile tool of manifest to be CTRPP. But when I compile it,
VS2013 reports that error:File not found and error:CTRPP failed, error code is -2147024894.
I searched online but cannot find any documents which can me the meaning of the error code. The manifest file is generated by ecmangen.exe, and it works well when I created a new project and compile it in the new project.
[image]

Comment: `-2147024894` in decimal translates to [`0x80070002`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319335.aspx) in hex. That's the error code for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, as you already discovered. There isn't anything more to it.

Comment: That's strange. I use the same command when I compile the manifest , but it report cannot find file, the file refers to the manifest file.

Comment: You are passing relative path names, which frequently leads to these kind of errors. Visual Studio's build tool defines a large number of variables that you can use to construct fully qualified path names in your custom build step.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. When I add the full path to the manifest file, it compiles perfectly! Thank you!